# Do ladders exist in the Medieval Age, or were they not invented until the Space Age?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Until now, I only was able to build Stairs or Small Stairs (half-width).

Obviously they are not fit for mineshafts, so, how to build Ladders?

I believe the technology to build wooden Ladders already existed on Medieval Age, since I myself built one this week from timber and nails, on my backyard (real world). It's not Rocket Science.

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=405

Comment: I don't know if that really qualifies as a bug. It's more of a feature request.

Comment: @TimmyJim I used the bugtracker to request the feature. Check the "Category" field. It says "Feature Request".

Comment: Ah! Ok! I saw that it had "steps to reproduce" which I thought was odd for something that isn't a bug and automatically assumed that it was listed as bug instead.

Comment: @TimmyJim Really odd, I admit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the looks of it, the vanilla game does not have ladders according to [this Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/333950/discussions/0/1471967615846949155/), and a few others such as [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/333950/discussions/0/1676938384249978624/).

The post links to [a mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1121540837) that seems to add a type of ladder, but it doesn't look like a straight vertical kind, but a slightly angled one, which I imagine can still be useful.